# Horizontally align floated texts to both sides of centered img

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to some concepts in HTML and CSS and this one I can't seem to wrap my head around. I'm trying to align two floating `<p>` elements to both sides of a centered `<img>`. Here's what I'm basically trying to achieve.
[image]

I want the two texts to stick to the sides of the centered image even when the window is at full width. I have it working only when I resize the window to the point where they're squished to the sides of the image.

```css
.header {
  margin-top: 85px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p style="float: left; margin-top: 115px;"><a href="#listen">listen</a></p>
  <img id="main_cover" src="img/into-me.png" width="250" height="250" draggable="false">
  <p style="float: right; margin-top: 115px;"><a href="#download">download</a></p>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, especially since this may be a dumb question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) or **CSS tables** [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/154/)

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a href="">Listen</a>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
  <a href="">Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful, works like a charm. Thank you so much Nenad!

Answer (score 0):

Do this...

```
<div class="header">
 <p><a href="#listen">listen</a></p>
 <img id="main_cover" src="img/into-me.png" width="250" height="250" draggable="false">
 <p><a href="#download">download</a></p>
</div>
```

And your CSS...

```
.header { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto}
.header img { margin: 0 20px; float: left; }
.header p { margin: 115px 0 0; float: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have just given the container a defined width so the floated elements wouldn't float further away as the window size changes:

```
.header {
  margin-top: 85px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 370px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8sfvgvgr/

Answer (score -1):

How about flexboxes to obtain this?

```css
header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items:center;
}

span{
  text-align:center
}

img{
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 250px;

}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Text</span>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/07/27/20/29/landscape-403165_960_720.jpg" alt="Landascape">
  <span>Text</span>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
}

.flex-item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">listen</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Image </div>
  <div class="flex-item">Download</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```